# Solution Items in Visual Studio 2005/2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Is it possible to add a class as a solution item and use it as a linked item in all the projects in the solution?

Basically I was thinking of creating a class (which will inherit `ConfigurationSection`) and keeping it as the Solution Item. I wanted to add it as a linked item in all the projects in the solution, so that everyone can use it to access the configuration properties.
(Refer to [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/jjameson/archive/2009/04/02/linked-files-in-visual-studio-solutions.aspx) for more details)

Now the issue I am facing is that when I create a class in the solution item, it doesn't have any namespace. And it shows up in intellisense, inside the projects but once I create an object of the solution item class, the object doesn't show up in intellisense.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be better off putting your class into a library and then people can reference your library and use your class. If you use the linking methodology, you will run into problems when one project wants to reference another as you will have the same class in both projects in the same namepsace - it will not compile.

**Update**

I can see from your other questions that you want to share configuration settings through a config file. Sharing the config file by linking is fine, it is just a plain text file so does not have any compilation issues. However, I would advise against sharing the class file using this method as discussed above. Put your configuration class in a class library project which other people can reference as a project reference - they can then use your class. Add the actual config file (with the settings) using linking. In this way your settings file will get copied across projects nicely, and people can use your configuration settings class by referencing it.

Comment: Really? If you check out the tutorial I referred in the question. He had two classes (AssemblyVersionInfo.cs and  SharedAssemblyInfo.cs) added as links in his projects.

Comment: thanks. thats exactly I wanted to do. Currently in my place, we had people actually creating separate configSections (and thus separate handlers for those sections) for each projects which not only meant having configuration code spread across multiple projects but sometimes we even needed to copy certain settings in multiple configSections if they were required in more than one projects. 

Your solution makes a lot of sense. All I need to know is how to create a class library now :)

Comment: @TimLloyd have almost the same problem. I have one solution with two projects. In one project i have an AppConfiguration.json file which holds the configurations which are necessary for both projects. Is it possible to share the same configuration through two projects - both are in one solution

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler The config file can be shared via linking and should work fine. Have the config checked in as part of one project, and then add the file as a link to the project you wish to share it with.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Right-click each project, click Add, Add Existing File, navigate to the file, then click the down arrow next to the Add button and click Add As Link.

However, it would be better to put the class in a DLL project that is referenced by all of the projects.